# Table and Image side by side

Tags: tables

Please help me out with my code.

1. I want to place table on left side and image on right side of slide.
2. I want table width equal to text inside it.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{b{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{changepage}

\begin{document}

      \begin{frame}{fIRST SLIDE}

            \tiny
            \setlength\tabcolsep{1pt}
            %       \adjustbox{max height=\dimexpr\textheight-5.5cm\relax,
            %           max width=\textwidth}
            %       T\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
            \begin{tcolorbox}[tabularx={C|C},% <-- main change 
                boxrule=0.5pt, title = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX]

                Number of blades &  XX \\ \hline 
                Rotor configuration &   upwind  \\ \hline
                Rotor diameter (m)& YY \\ \hline
                Rated power (kW) &  ZZ \\ \hline
                Hub height (m)  & XX \\ \hline
                Tower diameter top (m) &    XX \\ \hline
                Tower diameter base (m) &   XX  \\ \hline
                Wind speed (m/s) &  XX \\ \hline
                Rotation rate (rpm) & XX \\ \hline
                Blade pitch angle (\textsuperscript{0}) & XX \\ \hline
                Yaw angle (\textsuperscript{0})  & XX 
            \end{tcolorbox}

            \begin{figure}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{S809_WT.PNG}
                \caption*{Figure 2.1: XXXXXX}       
            \end{figure}


        \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you put your image into a `figure` environment. It tells LaTeX to put the image separately. I suggest to divide the frame into two columns. Since I don't have your image, the width of the columns is just a guess.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
  \usepackage{tabularx}
  \renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{b{#1}}
  \newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
  \usepackage{colortbl}
  \usepackage{tcolorbox}
  \usepackage{changepage}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{fIRST SLIDE}
  \begin{columns}
  \begin{column}{0.6\textwidth}
    \tiny
    \setlength\tabcolsep{1pt}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[tabularx={C|C},%
      boxrule=0.5pt, title = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX]
      Number of blades &  XX \\ \hline 
      Rotor configuration &   upwind  \\ \hline
      Rotor diameter (m)& YY \\ \hline
      Rated power (kW) &  ZZ \\ \hline
      Hub height (m)  & XX \\ \hline
      Tower diameter top (m) &    XX \\ \hline
      Tower diameter base (m) &   XX  \\ \hline
      Wind speed (m/s) &  XX \\ \hline
      Rotation rate (rpm) & XX \\ \hline
      Blade pitch angle ($^\circ$) & XX \\ \hline
      Yaw angle ($^\circ$)  & XX 
    \end{tcolorbox}
  \end{column}
  \begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{S809_WT.PNG}\\
    {\tiny Figure 2.1: XXXXXX}       
  \end{column}
  \end{columns}          
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative, with bigger used fonts, with automatically adjusted width of second table column, based on my understanding of question:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
  \usepackage{tabularx}
  \renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{b{#1}}
  \newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
  \newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
  \usepackage{colortbl}
  \usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
%  \usepackage{changepage}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{fIRST SLIDE}
    \footnotesize
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{cC}    
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
    width=0.62\textwidth,
    boxrule=0.5pt, 
%    
    tabularx={R|c},%
    title = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX]
Number of blades            &   XX      \\ \hline
Rotor configuration         &   upwind  \\ \hline
Rotor diameter (m)          &   YY      \\ \hline
Rated power (kW)            &   ZZ      \\ \hline
Hub height (m)              &   XX      \\ \hline
Tower diameter top (m)      &   XX      \\ \hline
Tower diameter base (m)     &   XX      \\ \hline
Wind speed (m/s)            &   XX      \\ \hline
Rotation rate (rpm)         &   XX      \\ \hline
Blade pitch angle ($^\circ$)&   XX      \\ \hline
Yaw angle ($^\circ$)        &   XX
    \end{tcolorbox}
&    
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}\newline
     Figure 2.1: XXXXXX
    \end{tabularx}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```